# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "inf" when reading from snowflake with Spark

Tags: apache-spark, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I've a Snowflake table that has a column with doubles. One of the values are `inf` and `-inf`.

When I try to read this table in Spark, the job fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "inf"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:285)
    at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:29)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Conversions$$anonfun$1.apply(Conversions.scala:156)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Conversions$$anonfun$1.apply(Conversions.scala:144)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Conversions$.net$snowflake$spark$snowflake$Conversions$$convertRow(Conversions.scala:144)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Conversions$$anonfun$createRowConverter$1.apply(Conversions.scala:132)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Conversions$$anonfun$createRowConverter$1.apply(Conversions.scala:132)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.CSVConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(CSVConverter.scala:73)
    at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.CSVConverter$$anonfun$convert$1.apply(CSVConverter.scala:34)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:410)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.next(InMemoryRelation.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:221)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1165)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

When looking at where the error happens, it seems to be in the row conversion in `Conversions.scala` with `data.toDouble`

```
at net.snowflake.spark.snowflake.Conversions$$anonfun$1.apply(Conversions.scala:156)
```

`data.toDouble` will not work if the input is `inf`. In scala the value should be Infinity instead. (which comes from `Double.PositiveInfinity.toString`)

What should be the workaround to avoid crashing in similar cases?

Comment: Have you already seen the data type mappings? https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/spark-connector-use.html#data-type-mappings

Comment: Thanks @RachelMcGuigan for the link, I see that Snowflake DOUBLE is mapped to Spark DoubleType (the connector code also confirms this). But the problem is the support for Infinity. i created an issue https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/issues/184

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed as of v 2.6.0 of the spark connector, [here is the PR](https://github.com/snowflakedb/spark-snowflake/commit/16573afff0eb1fafb177eee1b2479b66dba40346).